# Issue with application using lighttpd 1.4.40

Tags: lighttpd

I have moved from lighttpd version 1.4.35 to 1.4.40 and my application has stopped working.

Between lighttpd versions 1.4.35 and 1.4.40, this is the difference I have in terms of the request that lighttpd is forwarding to my application. With lighttpd 1.4.35, my application is able to respond whereas with 1.4.40, my application doesn't progress.

The only difference I am seeing is the bit I have highlighted in the image below. I am not sure if I am missing something in my application.

On the left is the trace with lighttpd 1.4.35 and on the right is the trace with lighttpd 1.4.40

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am not sure if I am missing something

You're missing over 5 years of lighttpd releases.  The lighttpd 1.4.40 was released Jul 2016.  lighttpd 1.4.64 was released Jan 2022.  If you are going to upgrade, then you should upgrade to a recent release.

IIRC, lighttpd 1.4.40 onwards defaults to offload the entire response from the backend before sending the response to the client.  You can use `server.stream-response-body = 1` in lighttpd.conf to change this default to stream the response.

Comment: Thanks @gstrauss.
Could you please elaborate the second para.
The reason we moved from lighttpd 1.4.35 to 1.4.40 was because lighttpd was staging files and to avoid it, we had used
server.stream-request-body = 1

Since you mentioned server.stream-response-body, I am afraid we could have missed something. What do you mean when you say " lighttpd 1.4.40 onwards defaults to offload the entire response from the backend before sending the response to the client"

Comment: `server.stream-response-body` was added in lighttpd 1.4.40.  The default is 0, which offloads the entire response from the backend before sending the response to the client.  Please see the [server.stream-response-body](https://wiki.lighttpd.net/Server_stream-response-bodyDetails) documentation.  Given the major oversight that caused you to consider lighttpd 1.4.40 an "upgrade" to such an ancient version, I highly recommend spending a minute reading https://wiki.lighttpd.net/